# Game Center in iOS 6

Tags: game-center, ios6, xcode4.5

I downloaded the XCode 4.5 + iOS 6 SDK Preview version, and ran Game-Center integrated app.

With prior versions, when I didn't enabled the game center in itunesconnect and ran the app, the message was shown as "This game is not recognized by Game Center".

But in iOS 6, Game Center login dialog was appeared even if this is not game center enabled in itunesconnect.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: iOS 6 was only released as a developer preview this week and as such, it's still under Apple's NDA. If anyone talks about iOS 6 outside of [Apple's official devforums](http://devforums.apple.com), Apple can terminate that person's developer account. If you want to talk about this on StackOverflow, it's best to wait until when iOS 6 is officially & publicly released.

Comment: From the [tag:ios6] wiki: "iOS6-specific questions should be avoided on Stack Overflow until the NDA is lifted."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to logout from the Game Center app and delete this app.
A lot of iTunes Connect related issues are solved by deleting the app.